# Count the no. of tables exported using expdp in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, expdp

I have a bash script in which I will be running the expdp command. Now, I would like to count the no. of tables exported using the expdp command.I need this, because sometimes the expdp can be halted in the middle and I would like to know, how many tables have been exported till that time.

The [expdp command syntax](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g#expdp) doesn't seem to have any option to count the no. of tables exported. Is there a way?

Comment: Can your bash script access the oracle directory where the dump is created? If yes, you could check the log file

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  yes, but does that contain the no. of tables?

Comment: Yes, it does (it's a bit complicated to parse, but the information is there)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  There is something like exported schema.table_name or something like that every line. I want count of the no. of tables only

Comment: e.g. `Completed 91 SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA objects in 4 seconds` or count the lines that contain `. . exported `

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, i cannot see that line. I can see Job "DBIMPL"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at Tue,..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - To count the no. of lines that contain .. exported, the lines can also contain views or triggers. So, they are not just tables only.

Answer (score 0):

Can examine the export log and count them

Cheers
Brian